# Should questions on Vagrant, Ansible, Docker and any other virtualization tools migrated to DevOPs SE?

Tags: discussion

Should questions on Vagrant, Ansible, Docker and any other virtualization tools migrated to DevOPs SE?

I feel like these go a bit beyond questions about Linux CLUIs, GUIs and shell scripting.

An exception could be say MySQL console, Composer, WP-CLI, Drush and other shell extensions but programs like Vagrant, Ansible, Docker which are virtualization tools, usually more complex, and fall under common definitions of "DevOPs" should maybe migrated to the (still beta) [DevOPs SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so, no. First because we don't migrate away questions that are on topic. Second because we cannot migrate any question that is older than 60 days, so this would only apply to very few questions anyway. Third because something like docker seems completely on topic here, I don't see why not. We have a lot of *nix sysadmins here, so that should fall under their area of expertise.

If a particular question is not a good fit here, then we can always migrate on a case by case basis, but I don't see much point in a blanket migration rule.

Comment: What, for examples, would seem relevant to you to be published on DevOPs SE on the first place?

Comment: @JohnDoea no idea. I don't know their scope, and I don't even really know what "devops" means. I just know what's on topic here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a DevOps SE person, yet I use docker and ansible daily.  Tooling, alone, does not make DevOps.  DevOps also requires process and methodology.

So I would say that technical questions around how these tools work at a Unix level ("docker doesn't work properly") would appear to be on-scope, but usage questions in how to make them work at a process layer ("how can I make Jenkins fire up docker containers for testing") may be better on a DevOps site.